# Shrew Soft VPN fail to attach key daemon

Tags: 14.04, networking, vpn

I'm trying to use Shrew Soft to connect to my school VPN. But as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUjSE.png), it says

> failed to connect to key daemon

I searched for the solution and people who use Shrew Soft Trace Utility and easily solved this on Windows OS as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/calpt.png).

Yet, I don't know how to solve this on Ubuntu 14.04.

Also, is there a substitute application for Shrew Soft VPN for Ubuntu?
Thanks!

Comment: What type of VPN does your school use? Shrew seems to only support open VPN protocols, so there are definitely native Linux clients out there. There's even a [Linux client](https://www.shrew.net/download/ike).

Answer (score 16):

You can always check it if it's running by using the following command:

`pgrep iked`

if you get a result, it means the process is running

if not run the below command:

`sudo /usr/sbin/iked`

it starts service

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I found out that **iked** service was not running. I solved it by opening a terminal emulator and issued the command:

```
sudo /var/tmp/ike/script/linux/iked start
```

I later found out that the Shrew installation on Ubuntu does not add this script to start up at all (shame on the guys and girls from Shrew ;-)). To do this yourself do the following:

1. In a terminal issue the command:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/rc.local
   ```
2. Type your root password and add the following line just before the last line (which normally says **exit 0**)

   ```
   /var/tmp/ike/script/linux/iked start
   ```
3. Save and close it.

Next time you restart your computer the service will be active and the error should never bother you again.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 20.04, enable iked on startup by creating a systemd unit file:

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/shrewvpn.service
```

with the contents:

```
[Unit]
After = network-online.target
Wants = network-online.target

[Service]
Type = oneshot
RemainAfterExit = yes
ExecStart = /usr/sbin/iked

[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

Enable your service on startup by issuing:

```
systemctl enable shrewvpn
```

and start it in the current session using:

```
systemctl start shrewvpn
```

Answer (score -1):

Look in services.msc, I'm assuming that one of the Shrewsoft services isn't running. Should have two or 2 of them(shrewsoft IKE Daemon, Shrewsoft IPSEC Daemon, and Shrewsoft DNS Daemon). You may not have the last one.

Comment: -1 because suggesting Windows-only solution. OP had mentioned that "Yet, I don't know how to solve this on Ubuntu 14.04. Also, is there a substitute [...] for Ubuntu?"